# Toggling one div causes another div to unexpectedly move

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got multiple divs on one page, each div has got a toggle on it. When the toggle is pressed, another div appears with extra information. The thing is, when I press the first div to toggle it, it makes the other divs unexpectedly move up.

HTML:

```
<div id="century14" class="century"></div>

<div id="century14text" class="centuryText">

  <p>Did you know that this this and that happened to William Shakespear in 1345.</p>

</div>

<div id="century15" class="century"></div>

<div id="century15text" class="centuryText">

  <p>Did you know that this this and that happened to Galileo Galilei in 1345.</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centuryText {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
  }

  .century {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .century:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #century14 {
    margin-left: 202.5px;
    margin-top: -361px;
  }

  #century14text {
    margin-top: -240.5px;
    margin-left: 125px;
  }

  #century15 {
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 95px;
  }

  #century15text {
    margin-top: -240.5px;
    margin-left: 240px;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(
      function(){
          $("#century14").click(function () {
              $("#century14text").fadeToggle();
          });
      });

  $(document).ready(
      function(){
          $("#century15").click(function () {
              $("#century15text").fadeToggle();
          });
      });
```

Also, if any of you know how I can improve my code in terms of layout or anything else, please tell me :D

Thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4mv6s6u4/   Basically you see two blue circles right? Well when you click the left one, the right one goes up, I want the right one to stay where it is. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Toggle will move everything below the element up. What you would want to use is a css selector to keep the elements where they originally are:

```
$('#century14text').css("visibility","hidden");
```

Then use this to make it visible again:

```
$('#century14text').css("visibility","visible");
```

Answer (score 0):

They "unexpectedly move up" because the hidden div now has `display:none` as part of its inline style (that's what jQuery does when it hides something by default).  Becuase it has `display:none` it is no longer in the document flow and has no size, all other content shifts to fill the gap.

> When called on a visible element, the element's display style property is set to none once the opacity reaches 0, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

You will need to write your own animation handlers to keep the div's virtual space using the [`.fadeToggle` `complete` callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/#fadeToggle-options).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by an animation handler?

Comment: @Happydude All of jQuery's animation shorthands (fade, toggle, hide, show) have callbacks that let you specify how to do those things manually, similar to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it without having to write too much script. This way if you need to add similar elements like this, you don't have to keep writing script for each id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".century").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

I added the class selector "hide" to your css:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

get rid of `display: none` in the `.centuryText` selector and this should work.